# Magento : Is It Possible to Call Model From Another Extension

Tags: magento-1.9, model, variables

I want to create custom module, but I need to acquire variable from another module.

I've looked into their code and this variable is result of many different functions in different Models, which I would like to avoid including in my module.

Is it possible to request variable from specific line in Model from  different module?

**Edit:**

For example:

I am only interested in getting the value (from a Model within a module) of:
 `$rates[$customMethod->getId()]['time']`,
where `$rates` and `$customMethod` are not easily traceable (with my Magento knowledge), so I am wondering if there is an easier way of achieving this without copying all of the Models being used by the module.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Added some clarification.

Comment: Yes it's Possible please go to this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811276/how-to-call-model-class-method-from-controller-in-megento

Answer (score 1):

If the module is active then You can call it from anywhere like this

```
$modelObj = Mage::getModel('Modulename/Modelname');
```

### EDIT

For this file `app/code/local/Amasty/Table/Model/Carrier/Table.php` you can call it this way `Mage::getModel('table/carrier_table');`

Comment: If call a Model that calls on other Models will everything execute as expected no matter from where I call it?

Comment: Also, if my Model path is: `app/code/local/Amasty/Table/Model/Carrier/Table.php`, I would call it by: `Mage::getModel('Table/Table');` or do I also have to include the subfolder `Carrier`?

Comment: You can call it like this way `Mage::getModel('table/carrier_table');`

Comment: Yes if you call a model from your code it is reasonable to expect that it works correctly.  The only time you have to worry is if you happen to see code that doesn't follow the magento standards while poking around their code.

Comment: I think he needs a variable value from another model, if he calls with "getModel" he will get another instance.

Comment: That is true. The reason why just calling the Model from my module won't work, is because the original extension calls it when specific prerequisites are met. It is too complex for me to check for all of them, that's why I want to just get the variable to my module whenever it is used by the other extension.

Comment: If I call the Model, is there any way to get a variable from that Model in my controller?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can access models anywhere, however I am not sure what you mean about a specific line. You could access any item but not just that item (you would need to load the whole model).

Comment: Added some clarification.

Comment: You would need to load the whole model, even if you only want to use part of it.